# How to apply UI props in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use an external UI Library and that library has a Button component.
I want to build a NewButton component that will take all props from the library Button component and will accept a few extra props that I will add on top of it (like 'url' and 'text' as shown below).

I tried something like that, not sure where to place the actual "...libraryButtonProps":

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "library/buttons";

interface NewButtonProps {
  text: string;
  url: string;
}

export const NewButton = ({ text, url, ...libraryButtonProps }: NewButtonProps) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>
      <Button>
        {text}
      </Button>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

For example, there is no need for me to code disabled={disabled} inside that Button, because it's already built-in from that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add your own props into the existing props of the library component using the `extends` keyword.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "library/buttons";

interface NewButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  text: string;
  url: string;
}

export const NewButton:React.FC<NewButtonProps> = ({ text, url, ...libraryButtonProps }) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>
      <Button {...libraryButtonProps} >
        {text}
      </Button>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should place the props on the Button component you originally imported, otherwise, the component wouldn't be aware of the forwarded props.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "library/buttons";

interface NewButtonProps {
  text: string;
  url: string;
  // Add the props of the original Button as valid 
}

export const NewButton = ({ text, url, ...libraryButtonProps }: NewButtonProps) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>
      <Button {...libraryButtonProps}>
        {text}
      </Button>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

That library should expose `ButtonProps`.

If not, then you could try the helper `React.ComponentProps` to extract the props from the exported component.

**Solution:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "library/buttons";

type LibButtonProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>
interface NewButtonProps extends LibButtonProps {
  text: string;
  url: string;
}

export const NewButton: React.FC<NewButtonProps> = ({ text, url, ...libraryButtonProps }) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>
      <Button {...libraryButtonProps}>
        {text}
      </Button>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```